# How to solve npm error in npx create react app

Tags: reactjs, node.js

While i write npx create react app it returns npm err. As shown on the fig[error on npx create-react-app my-app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YXW0f.jpg)

If it wore worked properly it came up with cd my-app npm start
Happy hacking! And i will procced to install all the node_modules
[npx create-react-app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X7Fvd.jpg)

Comment: Can you please tell what is your node version in your system? use "node -v" if you don't know how to check it.

Comment: node-V 20.11.1 npm -v 10.2.4

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Update your node version or try yarn package manager `npm i -g yarn`